# EEPROM.read data not comparing with DHT11 sensor value - Arduino temp controller

Tags: lcd, temperature-sensor, eeprom, atmega2560

I'm using a DHT11 to read temperature to control a relay that will control a fan. When 'A' is pressed it allows the user to update the temp value that the relay will go HIGH at. The value is being stored and read to and from the EEPROM but they are not being compared properly in the if statement. Please help!

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <dht11.h>                 
dht11 DHT;                 

char temperature[2];
char initial_temperature[2];
char new_temperature[2];
char key_pressed=0;

const int relay = 8; 
const int dht11_data = 6;     
int temp=0;
int relayState = LOW;         
int i=0;
int j=0;
int init_pass = 0;

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
//define the symbols on the buttons of the keypads
char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
{'1','2','3','A'},
{'4','5','6','B'},
{'7','8','9','C'},
{'*','0','#','D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {38, 40, 42, 44};
byte colPins[COLS] = {46, 48, 50, 52};

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

 //initialize an instance of class NewKeypad
 Keypad customKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);

 void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(relay, relayState);
 lcd.begin(16,2);
 lcd.print("  Welcome to ");
 lcd.setCursor(0,1);
 lcd.print("     Test 2");
 delay(2000);
 lcd.clear();


   }

void loop() {

DHT.read(dht11_data);
temp=DHT.temperature;

lcd.clear();                   
lcd.setCursor(5,0) ;         
lcd.print("Temp");            //display"Temp="
lcd.setCursor(5,1);
lcd.print(temp);
lcd.write(0xDF);              //Display custom characters '°'
lcd.print("C");

delay(200);               
initialtemperature();


       // here is the problem - comparing temp>=init_pass
 // 'temp' will not compare with value of 'init_pass' 
 // like it does with a number value in it's place.

for(int j=0;j<2;j++){   
init_pass = (initial_temperature[j] - '0');

if (temp >= (init_pass)){

 if(init_pass==2)
   relayState = HIGH;
   digitalWrite(relay,  relayState);

   Serial.print(init_pass);
  }
  }   

 key_pressed = customKeypad.getKey();
 if(key_pressed=='A')
 change();
}


void change(){
  j=0;
int i=0;
Serial.begin(9600);
lcd.clear();
lcd.print("FanOn Temp=");
lcd.print(initial_temperature);
// Serial.print(initial_temperature); 
lcd.write(0xDF);
lcd.write("C");   
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
lcd.print("New Temp=");
delay(200);
while(i<2)

{

char pressed=customKeypad.getKey();
if(pressed){
  new_temperature[i++]=pressed;
  lcd.print(pressed);
  EEPROM.write(j,pressed);
  j++;
}

pressed=0;

}
if(i==2){
lcd.write(0xDF);
lcd.write("C");         
delay(1000);
lcd.clear();
lcd.print("Saved");
delay(1000);
  }
  }

 void initialtemperature(){


for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
initial_temperature[j] = EEPROM.read(j);


}
```

Comment: temp is not comparing with init_pass ... if (temp >= (init_pass)){

 if(init_pass==2)
   relayState = HIGH;
   digitalWrite(relay,  relayState);

   Serial.print(init_pass);
  }

Comment: btw it was formatted until I posted it... not sure what I did

Comment: print as in Serial.print? I was using that for testing. If you mean something else, can you provide an example?

Comment: Don't post >100 lines of code and say something vague like "... they are not being compared properly in the if statement." Delete code that isn't germane to your question, and point out the specific line that is giving you trouble (along with a description of any setup or context we need in order to understand the line in question.)

Comment: the problem starts at: if (temp >= (init_pass)){     comparing temp>=init_pass
'temp' will not compare with value of 'init_pass'  like it does with a number value in it's place.

Comment: Everything in this sketch works up to this point.

Comment: you are misunderstanding the problem ..... the `if (temp >= (init_pass)){` also works correctly ..... it just does not give the results that you expect because the two values are not what you think they are     ........ as per my previous comment, what were the values of `temp` and `init_pass` and the length of `temp` and `init_pass` before the `if` statement?

Comment: So, to my understanding temp is a numeric or a integer value? and init_pass is converted to ASCII DEC value by using init_pass = (initial_temperature[j] - '0');? ...and the length off both is 2. it seems i either need to find a way to convert the 2 characters to one byte or write the value as one byte to begin with?